# Vector Proofs Help Please

Tags: geometry, vectors

Please help!!

I'm currently studying vector proofs and have no idea how I should even go about proving these questions. My teachers give little explanation and I cannot contact them as they are away. I apologise in advance for any incorrect formatting in my equations -- I've never written a post on here before.
Any advice would be GREATLY appreciated, but please may I request that explanations are written in such a way that a numpty like me could understand. Nothing overly-complicated please.

QUESTION 1:

Consider a circle with centre O and radius of **OA**=**a**. B and C are points on the circle with **BC**=**b**. 
Prove that the angle ABC subtended by a diameter of the circle is a right angle. 
They provide us with this diagram:
[image: diagram 1]

The only proofs I've seen so far that show the angle is 90 degrees initially define **OA**, **OB**, and **OC** as vectors **a**, **b**, and **c**, and find **BC** and **BA** in terms of these. They then show that the dot product of **BC** and **BA** is zero -- makes sense.

BUT this question has defined the **BC** as **b**, which I initially didn't think would be too much of a problem. I found the **OB** in terms of **OC** and **BC** (i.e. **OB** = -**a**-**b**) and found the **BA** in terms of **OA** and **OB** (i.e. **BA** = -**OB** + **a** = (**a** + **b**) + **a** = 2**a** + **b**). 
I then tried to prove that **BC** dotted with **BA** = 0. BUT this is where my difficulties appeared.
I figured:

**b** . (2**a** + **b**)

= **b** . (2**a**) + **b** . **b**

= 2(**a**.**b**) + |**b**|^2

but I could not figure out how to continue so as to prove that the dot product is zero. Maybe I've messed up in my method?

---

QUESTION 2: (please note this is entirely **unrelated** to question 1)

ABCD is a rectangle where point O is an origin **not** on the same plane as the rectangle. Prove that **OA** . **OC** = **OB** . **OD**

I haven't got a clue where to start with this one.

Any help given would be MAJORLY appreciated -- but please may I request once more that any help is explained in such a way that a student like me could understand (I'm not as good as you guys with your fancy proofs lol)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: Please, post only [one question in one post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7132/290189). Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6464/290189).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Hint: $|OB| = |OA|$ since they are radii of the same circle, so $|\vec{a}| = |-\vec{a}-\vec{b}|$.  Square this to get $$\vec{a}\cdot\vec{a} = (\vec{a}+\vec{b})\cdot(\vec{a}+\vec{b}).$$
   Then expand the RHS and cancel $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{a}$ on both sides to recover the expression that you've already got for $\vec{BA} \cdot \vec{BC}$.
2. Draw a diagram.  Let $\vec{AB}=\vec\ell$ and $\vec{AD}=\vec{w}$.  Then
   \begin{cases}
   \vec{OA}&=\vec{a} \\
   \vec{OB}&=\vec{a}+\vec\ell \\
   \vec{OC}&=\vec{a}+\vec\ell+\vec{w} \\
   \vec{OD}&=\vec{a}+{w}.
   \end{cases}
   Since $ABCD$ is a rectangle, $\vec\ell \cdot \vec{w} = 0$.  The rest of the proof should be straightforward, and I left this as exercise.

Comment: Thank you very much @GNUSupporter 8964民主女神 地下教會 , I believe I have been able to complete the proof for question 2 :). If possible, could you please elaborate on your advice about question 1? How do I square the magnitude of a vector? (i.e. doesn't it become the square root of its components squared? How would this be written in terms of vector a?) How does the squared magnitude "input" itself into the equation? Sorry to be a pain; thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: You *don't* need to ping a post owner with `@` because he/she will be notified in *any* case.  I've elaborated *a bit* more.  You'll get your *own* solution by expanding my hint.

Comment: Okay, I now understand that by expanding your equation allows the expression I arrived at to equal zero. So this proof required the use of two separate equations? One that indicates that BC . BA = 2(a . b) + |b|^2 , and one that indicates that 2(a . b) + |b|^2 = 0, which consequently indicates that BC . BA = 0. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you've got it.  It would be even *better* if you enclose your math with `$`, like `$2(a \cdot b) + |b|^2$` to get $2(a \cdot b) + |b|^2$.

Comment: Noted. Thank you ever so much for your help -- you have saved the day :)

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, please [consider "accept" the answer](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4945/290189) by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).